# NoClassDefFoundError - external jar file

Tags: java, jar, ejb, weblogic

I am developing a project based on EJB in JDeveloper and I need to import a jar file as an additional library in order of the normal working of the application.

I go to Project Properties/Add library/New, I find the jar file and enter the class and source path and add the library. Next, I start the weblogic server and deploy the project. After that I try to run the application but I see the folloing error: "javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:".

I have been trying to fix this problem, but I do not know where to configure the settings.

I will be very grateful if you give me some piece of advice! 
Thank you!

Comment: Please check you manifest file and see what import it is using.

Comment: I cannot find a MANIFEST.MF file in my project. Should I create one?

Comment: You should find it what build tool do you use ? Maven or ant or other ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar `ejb.jar` in the lib folder which is on classpath as it contains the `javax.ejb.EJBException` class.

Though you still have to find out what's actually causing the `EJBException`.

Comment: I put the jar file in the class path, but I still have the same error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, followed by the name of a class in the library